# Incrementing when not in for loop - Python

Tags: python

**Problem**

I'm trying to write a script that records a number of screenshots, but I'm having a problem naming my file.

---

**Try**

I'm trying to initial my `i=0` and increment it as I go.

I kept getting 1 on all of them.

My image getting replace during save, and all I got at the end is `1.png`.

I suppose to have 16 of them.

---

**Code**

```
    i = 0
    driver = self.driver
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("admin@benunets.com")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("admin")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/account")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Create").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Cancel").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i.fa.fa-trash-o").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Got it").click()
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/account/1002")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/access-point")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/0.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/access-point/000D6751560C")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/access-point/000D6751560C/08002785112C")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/captive-portal/admin")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/cloud-security")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/setting/mirroring")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/profile")
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+=1)+'.png')
```

Comment: I doubt your code even executes. Your `str(i+=1)` should raise a SyntaxError. `i+=1` is an assignment command, not an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting back to `i`. Hence `i` is always 0.
You need to increment `i` after saving screenshot.

```
driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+1)+'.png')
i += 1
```

Not sure how is your code desgined so I'm giving really basic starting point.
You can do something like this. This one assumes `today` is in a reachable scope.

```
def save_screenshot_with_increment(): #these parameters normally depends on your design
    global i
    driver.save_screenshot(today+'/admin/'+str(i+1)+'.png')
    i += 1
```

Now instead of calling `driver.save_screenshot`, you may call `save_screenshot_with_increment`

```
driver.get(self.base_url + "/cloud-security")
save_screenshot_with_increment()
```

Comment: Do I have to keep this adding this line all the time `i += 1` ?

Comment: Yes, else `i` will not change value.

Comment: Yes, if you want to increment after saving your screenshot each time

Comment: Ooo... **function** ...  that sound cool. Do you mind get me a couple lines to start ?

Comment: I will accept your answer. But if you can add that function that will be perfect.

Comment: You still have an assignment in the `save_screenshot()` parameters ;)

Comment: Wow. What you suggested is a really cool way of doing it ! Love it man !

Answer (score 0):

you need to increment i value for every iteration. like `i=i+1`

if not i value will be same for every iteration. i.e 1. 
thats why every time you are getting 1.png

Comment: I guess str(i+=1). gives you SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you dont you use loop for that something like                                         `for i in range(0,16):               
   print(str(i)+".png")`